# Animating a drawable on a canvas inside a surfaceview

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there a way to animate drawables on a canvas using the android built-in animation classes?

I’ve been modeling my test application, a game, after the example apps lunarlander and jetboy.  They contain a lot of reusable code, but they manually update the drawable objects in real time.  It seems like using the android animation built ins would be so much easier since they provide the type of animation I need…a simple linear movement.

Is there a way to do this, or am I better off updating my canvas in real time much like the example apps.

If there is a way, could anyone get me started with some sample code?  I am currently inheriting SurfaceView in my class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...I guess nothing is coming up.

I did it manually, and found out it wasn't really that hard, however the animation flies since I haven't introduced any timing yet.

Comment: So how exactly did it work for you? I find it a bit tricky to make it. Any code examples?